# How does values_list django work?

Tags: python, django

I have interesting experience with `value_list` and I don't know why is it acting in this way.

I want to update any value in `TestObject` has `value_1` to `value_2` and any value_2 to value_1. Where `value_1` and `value_2` from type Value and `TestObject` has a foreign key to Value.

This is my code:

```
def _swap(value_1, value_2):
    from_values_ids = TestObject.objects.filter(value=value_1).values_list('id', flat=True)

    to_values_ids = TestObject.objects.filter(value=value_2).values_list('id', flat=True)

    TestObject.objects.filter(id__in=from_values_ids).update(value=value_2)
    TestObject.objects.filter(id__in=to_values_ids).update(value=value_1)
```

I tested with TestObject has `value_1` but does not have any `value_2`.
The end result was nothing happened after running this function. After investigating I found the TestObject got updated to `value_2` after running:

```
TestObject.objects.filter(id__in=from_values_ids).update(value=value_2)
```

but it returned back after running

```
TestObject.objects.filter(id__in=to_values_ids).update(value=value_1)
```

I thought may be `to_values_ids` has lazy load that is why I added `print to_values_id`.

```
def _swap(value_1, value_2):
    from_values_ids = TestObject.objects.filter(value=value_1).values_list('id', flat=True)

    to_values_ids = TestObject.objects.filter(value=value_2).values_list('id', flat=True)

    print to_values_ids

    TestObject.objects.filter(id__in=from_values_ids).update(value=value_2)
    TestObject.objects.filter(id__in=to_values_ids).update(value=value_1)
```

But I got the same result. Although my print for `to_values_ids` has `[]`.

The way I fix it I created new lists with the ids and it worked but still needs to understand the core python how is it work? Any good explanation.

Comment: Try printing both. If your `to_values_ids=[]` that means that you're not updating anything!

Comment: The list to_values_ids before two updates are empty but after running TestObject.objects.filter(id__in=from_values_ids).update(value=value_2) it got changed. Why that is happened?

Comment: `QuerySets` are returned as values, not references, so that shouldn't be happening...

Comment: That is part of my confusion and I do not know what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is likely due to the fact that Django QuerySet values_lists return generators. Since 1.9, `QuerySet.values_list` implements an iterable class like [FlatValuesListIterable](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/db/models/query.py#L149) Prior to 1.9, `QuerySet.values_list` returned an instance of [ValuesListQuerySet](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/db/models/query.py#L1213)... Both of these return a generator, so the query is executed each time you access the variable (hence the behavior you were seeing when calling print).

The resulting object will behave a lot like a list, which is confusing, but if you need proof it's not a list, try this:

```
from_values_ids = TestObject.objects.filter(value=value_1).values_list('id', flat=True)
from_list_ids = [obj.id for obj in TestObject.objects.filter(value=value_1)]
combined_list = from_values_ids + from_list_ids
```

... this will result in:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ValuesListQuerySet' and 'list'
```

The solution is simply to cast your `from_values_ids` variable as a list:

```
from_values_ids = list(TestObject.objects.filter(value=value_1).values_list('id', flat=True))
```

or just generate the list yourself:

```
from_values_ids = [obj.id for obj in TestObject.objects.filter(value=value_1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. [Django querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

```
from_values_ids = TestObject.objects.filter(value=value_1).values_list('id', flat=True) # doesn't hit the db

to_values_ids = TestObject.objects.filter(value=value_2).values_list('id', flat=True) # doesn't hit the db
```

Now when you do:

```
TestObject.objects.filter(id__in=from_values_ids).update(value=value_2)
                                   |                  
                                   |__> will fetch from db
```

Now all the values that matched `value_1` got updated to `value_2`. Now next line is executed:

```
TestObject.objects.filter(id__in=to_values_ids).update(value=value_1)
                                      |
                                      |__> Will actually execute the query you assigned it
                 # TestObject.objects.filter(value=value_2).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

At this moment all the objects that match `value_2` are fetched and updated to  `value_1`

But you see no difference because you have all `value_1` in the database before starting. Hence  `from_values_ids` fetches all the objects and updates them to `value_2` and then back to `value_1`. See having a mix of `value_1` and `value_2` records in the database. The difference will be evident.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! But when I called the print now it supposed that loaded the to_values_ids with [] but after running the first update it got updated. So it is not only lazy load it has been updated again, which I do not understand.

Comment: @amm Printing a queryset only queries for the first 20 or so elements of the queryset. Since that may not be the whole queryset, it isn't cached. Even if it is the whole queryset, consistency is chosen over optimization, and the queryset isn't cached. If you iterate the queryset or call `list()`, `len()` or `bool()`, the whole queryset is evaluated and cached.